# Insert Data to SugarCRM module from Android App

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2, sugarcrm

I want to insert some data from android application and insert in sugarcrm module. can anybody give me some hint? How to make soap client here? What is the right syntax ? I shall be very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of resources on how to implement web services on android and also how to connect to sugar. So basically:

- Create an Android App that can connect to a SOAP web service - [Example](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/167-using-ksoap2-for-android-soap-web-service)
- Check out the SugarCRM [documentation](http://support.sugarcrm.com/02_Documentation/04_Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/02_Application_Framework#Web_Services) for available web service methods

You can also check out a google code project called "[Sugadroid](http://code.google.com/p/sugadroid/)".